# wrong activity is started in android app

Tags: android, android-manifest

I am trying to fix the issue for hours but I couldn't. The app is not launching activity I mentioned in the manifest, see following

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    package="green.thumbup"
    android:versionCode="1"
    android:versionName="1.1" >

    <uses-sdk
        android:minSdkVersion="12"
        android:targetSdkVersion="17" />

    <uses-feature
        android:glEsVersion="0x00020000"
        android:required="true" />

    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_COARSE_LOCATION" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE" />
    <uses-permission android:name="com.google.android.providers.gsf.permission.READ_GSERVICES" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_NETWORK_STATE" />

    <permission
        android:name="green.thumbup.permission.MAPS_RECEIVE"
        android:protectionLevel="signature" />

    <supports-screens android:anyDensity="true" />

    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.CALL_PHONE" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_MOCK_LOCATION" />

    <application
        android:icon="@drawable/app_icon"
        android:label="@string/app_name"
        android:theme="@style/AppTheme" >
        <meta-data
            android:name="com.google.android.maps.v2.API_KEY"
            android:value="" />

        <activity android:name=".driver.DriverMap" >
        </activity>
        <activity android:name=".driver.Journey" >
        </activity>
        <activity android:name=".journey.PassengerDestination" >
        </activity>
        <activity android:name=".login.Login" >
        </activity>
        <activity android:name=".passenger.PassengerDestination" >
        </activity>
        <activity android:name=".passenger.PassengerInfo" >
        </activity>
        <activity android:name=".users.RegisterUser" >
        </activity>
        <activity android:name=".users.UserChoice" >
        </activity>

        <activity android:name=".driver.ThumbUpGoogleMap" >
            <intent-filter>
                 <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />                
                <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
            </intent-filter>
        </activity>
    </application>

</manifest>
```

ThumbUpGoogleMap is in green.thumbup.driver.ThumbUpGoogleMap package.The application is always launching Loging activity from green.thumbup.login.Login, which is old main activity. Login was launch in the previous build but I completely removed and rebuilding the application.

I tried following but not success

- I cleaned the code multiple times
- I created a new AVD
- I change activity path to android:name="green.thumbup.driver.ThumbUpGoogleMap"
- Also tried

This is driving me crazy, any hint, suggestion would be of great help

Comment: what is logcat error?

Comment: Have you tried clean and build project again ?

Comment: @Pankaj: there is no error just launching different activity

Comment: put your complete manifest

Comment: @amjad which activity is getting launched...

Comment: green.thumbup.login.Login

Comment: Your manifest is correct. For test remove entry of Login from manifest and then run and see logcat, if error.

Comment: [2013-07-04 14:02:44 - thumbup_client] The specified activity does not exist! Getting the launcher activity.
[2013-07-04 14:02:44 - thumbup_client] No Launcher activity found!
[2013-07-04 14:02:44 - thumbup_client] The launch will only sync the application package on the device!

Comment: getting above error when I remove it

Comment: :D something going wrong with cleaning the project. You should restart the eclipse and build again the project. :D

Comment: it is really weird, I am closing Eclipse, removing APK and rebuilding it. Still no luck

Comment: Try a last way, check run configurations. If there set for Login.

Comment: didn't get it , how to run configuration ?

Comment: right click on project -> run -> run configurations -> and watch your project there and see if launch action is set

Comment: that was not set in configuration. Now it works!!! Thanks a lot

Comment: now I am getting error "07-04 12:24:26.240: E/AndroidRuntime(2695): java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to instantiate activity ComponentInfo{green.thumbup/green.thumbup.driver.ThumbUpGoogleMap}: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: Didn't find class "green.thumbup.driver.ThumbUpGoogleMap" on path: /data/app/green.thumbup-2.apk
"

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
 <activity android:name=".driver.ThumbUpGoogleMap" >   
         <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

            <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
        </intent-filter>

    </activity>
```

EDIT:

If this doesnt solves the issue.. make this 4 lines

```
  <intent-filter>
        <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

        <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
    </intent-filter>
```

are used only once in the manifest file between any activity tags

Comment: post your complete manifest.. i always used this to change the launch activity everytime.. kindly see the new edit i have done

Answer (score 0):

Please write these two lines with activity declaration. And try to give full name for activity instead of just

**.driver.ThumbUpGoogleMap**

```
<activity android:name="green.thumbup.driver.ThumbUpGoogleMap" >
       <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

            <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
        </intent-filter>
</activity>
```

And remove  **`<action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />`** from your Main Activity declaration.

Comment: You have to clean your project properly and restart eclipse and then try it.